# How to fix the geocode error: UnicodeEncodeError ascii codec can't encode character ufeff and xfc

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geocoding, mmqgis

I'm struggling with geocoding on QGIS3 on a Mac 10.14.1.

When I try to import a CSV file from Excel via MMQGIS->Geocode->Geocode CSV with Google/Open Street Map, I get the error:

[image]

My guess is that Microsoft Excel is not saving the file correctly in UTF-8, even though I'm saying that it should save it like this. I have found a workaround, that takes a bit time unfortunately.

I'm uploading the CSV file to google spreadsheet and export it as a csv file.

However, now I'm getting another error and I don't find a workaround for this...

[image]

Do you have an idea how I can fix this problem?

I fear that the problem might be something with German Umlauts like 
üäö, but I really need this for joining tables etc...

Here is a simple excel table for you to test my issue.

[Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SKxx_3xMNPWDiBp6LPSiS5zJkmfm1qvCoJNYDQyiXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The first error is somehow related to BOM marker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string. Try to open the csv file with for example Notepad++ and save as UTF-8 without BOM and see if it helps.

Comment: @user30184 how would you do this on a mac where there is no notepad++?

Comment: Try https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mac+remove+bom&t=ffsb&ia=web, maybe you can find something.